# InvalidCharacterError: String contains an invalid character React svelte-carousel

Tags: reactjs, npm

So I have install svelte-carousel via `npm install svelte-carousel -D`
In my footer.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Carousel from 'svelte-carousel';
// import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

export default function Footer() {
    return (
        <div className="c-footer">
            <div className="c-slider-container">
                <Carousel
                    autoplay
                    autoplayDuration={5000}
                    autoplayProgressVisible
                    pauseOnFocus
                    arrows={false}
                >
                    <div>Some div</div>
                    <div>Some div2</div>
                    <div>Some div3</div>
                </Carousel>
            </div>
            <div className="c-gold-container">
            </div>
            <div className="c-contact-container">
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

And I get `InvalidCharacterError: String contains an invalid character`
When I remove the Carousel component, everything works fine

Comment: could it because the package is for svelte and not for react

Comment: Oh. I didn't think of that. I will use this then https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive-carousel. Thanks